# Burned component help!

Tags: components

My central heating mixing valve is down...
There is a clearly burned component, right next to the blue thing (capacitor).
Can someone tell me what that is?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Can we get a close-up?

Comment: No, nobody can. First, there are three blue things, two of them might be capacitors, but the third is most likely a varistor. However, in any case, there is nothing "clearly burned" anywhere. This mess of a question needs to be closed.

Comment: I tryed to, but I only have my phone as camera and could't really get a better picture. Is the one above those two white things, and to the right of the blue ones...

Comment: Presumably VR1 is not a capacitor, and C1,C9 are. Look at the Mini-MELF package above the upper optoisolator (right of C9). There is evidence of magic smoke on the PCB under it. No way to know what that part is, unfortunately, or what else on the board is damaged. It's dead, jim...

Comment: Thank you Brian, that component is the one I actually ment. I took better pictures, http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g30faebee842f1ddd999578239ccd98834032ef1f2  Do you think I can just replace that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can someone tell me what that is?**

[image]

It looks like a SMD cylindrical resistor ([MELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MELF_electronic_components) packaging)

[image]

The [colour code](http://www.vishay.com/docs/49617/mi0008.pdf) might be incomplete but it might enable you to work out the value.

[image]

> **Do you think I can just replace that component?**

You can try but there is usually a reason why components fail like that and the cause of that failure often affects other components too.

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question. I actually replaced the resistor whit another one slightly bigger in value. Is now working.